# What can be used to prevent the termination/killing of a process, even by the root user?

Tags: process, kill

Is there a security framework or general tool that can be used to ensure that a certain process started at boot in Linux *cannot* be terminated by any user or other process, including the root user?

Comment: See [SELinux](http://selinuxproject.org/).

Answer (score 3):

In short: no. The root user can do anything without restriction. Even *init* can be killed by root (which brings the system down.)

Comment: I see.  I was pretty sure that there were security frameworks out there that limited even what the root user was able to do.  Thanks for the response.